# Empty initial view controller, viewWillAppear() and viewDidAppear() not called

Tags: swift, macos

I created a super simple stopwatch app for mac os that was working perfectly a few weeks ago.
Today, I wanted to modify something but I realised that my **initial view controller was totally empty**. I can't understand what is happening, I'm thinking about an Xcode update or something like that ?

`viewDidLoad()` is called, but `viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()` are not.
I might have a new error message though :

`Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): *** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter`

On my storyboard, the window content of my `NSWindowController` is set to my initial view controller.

I repeat that everything was working perfectly a few weeks ago, does anybody have any idea about that problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The most significant information is **`[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter`**. Somewhere an `NSURL` is going to be created with a `nil` parameter

Comment: Don't add the solution to your question. A question should remain a question. If you found a solution to your issue, you can post an answer yourself - or of course accept an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you may have renamed a file without updating the references to it.

Comment: But why would `viewDidLoad()` be called but not `viewWillAppear()` nor `viewDidAppear()` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom TabController or NavigationController and you add your viewController there, make sure you call super.ViewWillAppear() in TabController, NavigationController, or even if you extend another controller, you should add it too. If you don't make it, you won't call ViewWillAppear, ViewDidAppear. I had the same problem 2 weeks ago.